# Codeigniter URL Redirect WITHOUT adding index.php

Tags: apache, codeigniter, redirect

I'm working on a site with a few controllers, and have configured my server to redirect requests for `http://www.host.com/controller/function/params` to`http://www.host.com/index.php/controller/function/params` using some simple regular expression matching in the apache config.  Now, I am trying to get one of my controllers to redirect to another one, but without adding the `index.php` to the URL, which is what the `redirect()` function does.  Is there an easy way to do this in codeigniter?  Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use `redirect`. It only adds `index.php` if it is configured as your index page.

So, check your `index_page` configuration. It should be an empty string:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

File: `app/config/config.php`

More info: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=mod_rewrite [Updated Version]

Comment: By the way, does that config parameter affect anything else in codeigniter or is it strictly for the redirect?

Comment: If affects several URL related functions, like `site_url()`, for example (which btw is used by `redirect`)

Comment: Thank you! Real simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, so simple and just does as expected.

Comment: Worked for me Thanks

Comment: worked in Codeigniter 4 in `app/config/App.php`

Answer (score 1):

I used 
$config['index_page'] = '';
it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you needs to add another .htaccess to root folder of your codeignitor based project and write there some redirect rules as below example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeignitortest/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

or can make below in application/config/config.php

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = '';