# Redirect does not load the page

Tags: php, redirect, codeigniter-4

Trying to redirect in Ci4 but getting an error. Found similar post w/ diff error message.

Ci4
Php 8.1.20

After deleting a post, trying to redirect to /blog page
[image: delete()]

Have the route in the routes.php
[image: routes.php]

Post successfully deletes from DB but page redirects to:
[image]

Do not understand why it's trying to load index.php instead of the baseURL/blog?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths in the [`to()`-function-call](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html?highlight=redirect#redirect-to-a-uri-path):

```php
return redirect()->to('blog');
```

Comment: Same result after I removed the '/'. Still directing to ...index.php

Comment: Do the other routes work correctly? Is this on local or production server? What is the baseURL (in Config/App.php or .env)?

Comment: Yes, other routes work...Local server.
.env app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/'

Comment: And what is the value of your `$indexPage` in `Config\App.php`? [Related Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492700/codeigniter-url-redirect-without-adding-index-php/9492809#9492809)

Comment: public string $indexPage = 'index.php?';

Comment: I modified the .env to include 8080, app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/', it loads the index page now (vs error). But it supposed to redirect to the Blog controller. Found this about redirect->
"redirect->to() does not perform a redirect immediately, on the spot, when called. It returns an object that in the end, must be returned by the Controller itself in order to work."
Per my original post, the delete(), where the redirect() is called, is in the Blog class, therefore I would think that it is being returned by the Blog controller...?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say. Does it work now or not?

Comment: No it was not working but I just found the solution: index_page configuration. It should be an empty string.

Comment: That's what i linked in the related Question/Answer.

Answer (score 0):

index_page configuration. It should be an empty string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).